# Laravel yajra-datatable select where in datatable

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I want to select all rows in datatable where inst_id = ?,
this is my code

```
if(request()->ajax()) {
        return datatables()->of(Domain::select([
            'id', 'domain', 'logo', 'description', 'created_at'
        ]))
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->addColumn('action', function($data){

               $btn = '<a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>';

               $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteTodo">Delete</a>';

                return $btn;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->make(true);
    }
    return view('functions/study/domain');
```

Comment: Have you tried `Domain::select([...])->where('inst_id', $id)` ?

Comment: Watch closely the parentheses

Comment: Thanks it worked,

Comment: No problem. I posted it as answer so you can mark yourquestion as resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add whatever queries you want with the base query

```
$id = 1;
if(request()->ajax()) {
        return datatables()->of(
            Domain::select([
                'id', 'domain', 'logo', 'description', 'created_at'
            ])
            ->where('inst_id', $id)
        )
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->addColumn('action', function($data){

               $btn = '<a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>';

               $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteTodo">Delete</a>';

                return $btn;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->make(true);
    }
    return view('functions/study/domain');
```